# Converting list of tuples (of different length) into dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

I am new to python and can not figure out how I can convert this list "groups" into dictionary "groups_dic" in such a way that every string of tuple is assigned as key in "group_dic"

```
groups = [("starch"), ("nuts", "vegetable"), ("fruits"), ("meat"), ("fruits"), ("starch")]
groups_dic = {}
```

This is the result I want by eliminating repeated strings:-

```
>>> print(groups_dic)

{"starch" : None,
"nuts" : None,
"vegetable" : None,
"fruits" : None,
"meat" : None}
```

Comment: That's not a list of tuples.

Comment: As @superbrain says, that's not a list of tuples. `[type(o) for o in groups]` gives me `[<class 'str'>, <class 'tuple'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>]`. Parentheses around a single value does not make it a tuple. This is a tuple with a single value: `('foo',)`. Note the trailing comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly, this is a pretty straightforward way to basically gather unique keys for a dictionary given a list of strings and/or tuples of strings

```
groups = [("starch"), ("nuts", "vegetable"), ("fruits"), ("meat"), ("fruits"), ("starch")]
groups_dic = {}


for group in groups:
  if type(group) != tuple:
    groups_dic[group] = None
  else:
    for element in group:
      groups_dic[element] = None
```

How will you be using the dictionary moving forward? Are you just trying to gather unique elements? If so , you can use a set instead of a dictionary.

Comment: Thanx brother your code really worked.. thanx alot :).Well I just want size of this dictionary to put forward in my code :D

Comment: no problem, if you just want the size (as in number of unique keys) , you can and still should use a set.  switching the dict out for a set is pretty straightforward and will be more efficient I believe.  also, if the answer worked out for you I'd appreciate clicking the checkmark to mark as the best/selected answer  ;)

Comment: The reason I am not using sets is that the strings will get unordered in them and every time I will be getting strings in different arrangement on printing. I already clicked the checkmark. Thankyou :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [itertools.chain](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) and [dict.fromkeys](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys)

```
from itertools import chain

groups = [("starch",), ("nuts", "vegetable"), ("fruits",), ("meat",), ("fruits",), ("starch",)]
res = dict.fromkeys(chain.from_iterable(groups))
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
{'starch': None, 'nuts': None, 'vegetable': None, 'fruits': None, 'meat': None}
```

Comment: Thanku brother for your guidance. I really appreciate your help. This code works fine for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have this list of tuples

```py
groups = [
    ("starch",),
    ("nuts","vegetable"),
    ("fruits",),
    ("meat",),
    ("fruits",),
    ("starch",),
]
```

you can use these one-liners:

```py
groups_dic = dict((string,None) for group in groups for string in group)
print(groups_dic)

groups_dic = {string:None for group in groups for string in group}
print(groups_dic)
```

Answer (score 0):

With some `for` loops and conditions:

```
for grp in groups:
    if type(grp) == tuple:
        for i in grp:
            if i not in groups_dic:
                groups_dic[i] = None
    elif type(grp) == str:
        if grp not in groups_dic:
            groups_dic[grp.replace('(','').replace(')','')]=None
                       
print(groups_dic)
```